# Need advice about using on the use of technology (WCF, Web services, etc..)

Tags: wpf, wcf, remoting

I have an WPF application. The problem: need program(daemon, service) that send signals by network to my wpf application and fires some events in real time. Need recomendations how to write this service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend looking into [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx).

This would allow you to use a variety of transport mechanisms, and is really the preferred IPC technology for .NET at this point.  It really should replace remoting for any new development.